# How can I add a restriction so that the # of forward steps won't overshadow the # of backward steps?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, iteration, motion

I have to create a program that tracks a person's motion. F represents forward B represents backward. The values are to be randomly generated between 2-20 as well as the total # of steps being randomly generated from 10-85 (total will decide when the steps will stop). The # of forward steps has to be greater than the # of backwards steps (always). My problem is that if my total is a number that's not so far from the # of steps forward, my # of backwards steps aren't even fully generated once. For example, I generated my program and it gave me an output of this:
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFBBBBB 13 steps from start
Forward: 18 Backward: 14 Total: 23
But the backwards steps weren't even able to be completed. How can I make it so this won't occur? Do I have to add a restriction?

Here's my code:

```
import random

while True:
    fwd= random.randint(2,20)
    bkwd= random.randint(2,fwd-1)
    total=random.randint(10,85)
    f= 0
    b = 0
    t= 0
    steps_taken= 0

    if bkwd > fwd:
        break

    while total > 0:
        f = 0

        while fwd > f:
            if total > 0:
                print("F", end="")
                f=f+1
                t=t+1
                total=total-1
                steps_taken= steps_taken+1

            else:
               f = fwd


        b = 0

        while bkwd > b:
            if total > 0:
                print("B", end="")
                t=t-1
                b=b+1
                total=total-1
                steps_taken= steps_taken+1
            else:
                b = bkwd
    if f > total:
        break

print(" ",t, "steps from the start")
#I need help here printing the right amount of total steps
print("Forward:", f, "Backward:", b, "Total:", steps_taken )
```

Here are my instructions:
A person walks a random amount of steps forward, and then a different random number of steps backwards.

The random steps are anywhere between 2 and 20
The number of steps forward is always greater than the number of steps backwards
That motion of forward / backward random steps repeats itself again and again
The motion is consistent (the number of forward steps stays the same throughout the motion, and the number of backwards steps stays the same throughout the motion)
After making a specific amount of total steps the person is told to stop and will be a certain amount of steps forward from where they started.

The total number of steps is generated randomly and will be between 10 and 85
You are writing a program to simulate the motion taken by the person.

Display that motion and the number of steps he ends away from where he started.
For Example:

If the program generated the forward steps to be 4, and the backward steps to be 2, and the total number of steps to be 13, your program would display:
FFFFBBFFFFBBF = 5 Steps from the start
If the program generated the forward steps to be 5, and the backward steps to be 3, and the total steps to be 16, your program would display
FFFFFBBBFFFFFBBB = 4 Steps from the start

Comment: If the number of forward steps is `18`, and the number of backward steps is `2`, I cannot see how you could get a solution for total steps of `10` ?? Unless I am not interpreting the  instructions properly ?? Unless, you get the total steps **first** and then calculate a random fwd and bkwd number of steps that take that limitation into consideration.

Comment: The total steps is 23, foward is 18 and backward is 14. but the program stops at the 5th backward step because the total steps reach 23. this means the 14 backward steps weren't even generated.

Comment: What about the situation that I explained - what would happen then ?

Comment: Well then F would be generated the whole 10 times and the backwards steps wouldn't even appear

Comment: Is that appropriate ? i.e. is that option satisfactory ?

Comment: I don't think that would happen

Answer (score 1):

I would tackle it like this:

```py
import random

total_steps = random.randint(10, 85)
fwd = random.randint(3,(20, total_steps-1)[total_steps<21])
bkwd= random.randint(2,fwd-1)

if (fwd+bkwd) > total_steps: 
    bkwd = total_steps-fwd

print("Total_steps=", total_steps, ", fwd=", fwd, ", bkwd=", bkwd)

# Initialise step pattern to a blank string, and steps to zero.
step_pattern = ""
steps = 0
while total_steps > 0:
    for i in range(fwd):
        step_pattern += "F"
        steps += 1
        total_steps -= 1
        
    if total_steps > 0:
        for j in range(bkwd):
            step_pattern += "B"
            steps -= 1
            total_steps -= 1

# Use f-strings to insert (step_pattern) and (steps) into string
print(f"{step_pattern} = {steps} steps from the start")
```

**Example OUTPUTs:**

```
Total_steps= 45 , fwd= 5 , bkwd= 2
FFFFFBBFFFFFBBFFFFFBBFFFFFBBFFFFFBBFFFFFBBFFF = 21 steps from the start
```

```
Total_steps= 14 , fwd= 6 , bkwd= 5
FFFFFFBBBBBFFF = 4 steps from the start
```

Comment: The simplification of the code makes it look really clean and removes unnecessary memory allocations. But, I believe the while loop is really unnecessary to check whether x > total_steps. Here, you are making total_steps as the domain, and calculating fwd and bkwd on the basis. But, in the worst worst case scenario, the loop may run infinitely provided the sum of total_steps is always smaller, which is practically impossible without any bias.

Comment: The sum of fwd_max and bkwd_max would be 40, compared to max_steps which is 85. I understand the possibility of an infinite loop, however, the probability of that happening is incredibly low due to the nature of the random function.

Comment: The probability of the first while loop - looping more than 4 times is next to none (according to my tests i.e. 0 out of 100,000).

Comment: I am not criticizing the while loop to check x. It was just a suggestion, as you have removed most of unwanted stuff from the original code, the while loop is little unwanted. As for the probability, by calculations, it would be 0.00168918918 chance of getting an infinite loop, which is extremely low.

Comment: Yes - thank you - but I am not sure how I would improve it based on the idea of keeping fwd and bkwd below the total steps, ensuring that one complete round of fwd and bkwd was "always" achieved.

Comment: If you keep `fwd = random.randint(3,(19, total_steps-1)[total_steps<20])`, to manipulate fwd on the basis of total_steps, and then find bkwd. And another `if` statement `if (fwd+bkwd) > total_steps: bkwd = total_steps-fwd` to keep check the restrictions. The code with while loop is 2.38ms per loop and the one with changes is 1.86ms per loop tested in Google Colab.

Comment: Updated based on excellent recommendation by @8D Masters

Comment: Why does it break if total_steps < 1?

Comment: Also, could you please explain why you made step_pattern = '' ? I don't understand how count worked for "". And in the last print statement, what does the f outside do?

Comment: Ok - thanks for pointing out the breaks, I think I forgot to remove them. I have now updated the code and added comments to help explain. Please let me know if you need further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If I would not have to complicate things, I would just set the `total` steps taken random generation from the sum of `fwd` and `bkwd`. And as per the requirements mentioned, the sum will not be greater or equal to 85.

```py
total=random.randint(fwd+bkwd,85)
```